# AS3 air multiple apps required to use APNS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I have 2 versions of the same app, one for iPad the other for iPhone. The app requires APNS services but could someone explain the setup of App ID's, provisioning files, and certs.

Let me explain what I have done and please correct me if I am wrong.

I have created an app id which has push notifications enabled. I have also created a distribution cert converted to P12. I also have a distribution provisioning file that is linked to app id com.myapp. Now, in the iPad app which has already been approved and sent to the app store uses u26hiu61.* (example) in the application description file. The iPhone version is ready to be sent to apple for approval but can I use the same app ID in the iPhone version? So basically have exactly the same app description file (other than the targeted device).

So can I pretty much use all the same certs, provisioning profiles and APNS cert for the second app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can publish a single app in the appstore and have it available for ipad and iphone.

You specify the devices to support in the app descriptor file:

```
<iPhone>
    <infoAdditions>
        <![CDATA[
            <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
            <array>
                <string>1</string>
                <string>2</string>
            </array>
            ...your other settings
        ]]>
    </infoAdditions>
</iPhone>
```

Where the 1 signifies iphone and 2 is for ipad.

So yes, you can use same certs, provisioning files etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks I realise that however the assets and stage has not been setup to use both iPad and iPhone. Lot's of absolute positions. iPad was built first and then the requirements changed.

Comment: Ok. If you're publishing 2 apps, they'll need different app ids - so different certificates.

Comment: Bugger! Was hoping that wasn't the case. THanks